# Style SVG with CSS only

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, svg

I'm trying to style a svg with css.
Particulary I'm trying to round the borders of an rect.
In Chrome(Version 51.0.2704.103 m) it works perfectly by setting the ry-Attribut to my selected Value.

```
rect#colorBack {
ry: 77;}
```

But when using IE (Version 11.0.9600.18349) or Firefox (Version 47.0) this attribue is ignored.
Does anyone know how to do this if it is only possible to modify with css?

Comment: share your code, or make some fiddle or plunkr

Comment: what about rx and ry attributes?

Comment: @MandeepSingh sorry, added missing code

Comment: @Markus Maisch: Here is a detail explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Fills_and_Strokes#Using_CSS

Comment: @Markus Maisch: SVG (basic support): http://caniuse.com/#feat=svg-css

Comment: @SayedRafeeq unfortunately there are no tips about rounding borders of a svg rectangle at all